# Does the polarized light lose intensity when it crosses a birefractive crystal?

Tags: optics, polarization, birefringence

If a beam of light coming from a natural source passes through a polarizer and then through a birefringent crystal, does the intensity with which it left the polarizer change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, whether you are asking about polarized light or natural light (unclear). In a non-absorbing crystal like calcite, natural light will split in two beams: the ordinary (Snell's law) ray and the extraordinary ray.

Comment: though the polarization might change after the birefringent crystal. So if you add another polarizer parallel to the first one after the birefringent crystal the overall transmission might be reduced, as well.